# SQL\ HTML Databases

Tags: html, sql, textbox, textarea

I was actually doing somthing else and came accross this intresing W3schools tutorial/ section in relation to SQL databases (its a curiousity killed the cat thing more then anything)

The page link where my question comes from is as follows

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_where

the example lists all records that include mexico in the countrys catagorie

I can for instance change this to spain and all entrys with spain are filterd through.

The question I have is, it seems very unlikely to me that an end user is going to type out the entire code

```
    SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country='Mexico';
```

everytime they want too search a city (this example thus being mexico). I'm presuming we can get the city name inserted from a textbox, but ive looked can cant fand any examples on how to do this?

Comment: "I'm presuming we can get the city name inserted from a textbox" — Yes.

Comment: "cant fand any examples on how to do this" — Start by picking a programming language (one that is supported by your webserver and not client side JavaScript). Then look for a general web programming tutorial for that language. Taking user input from forms is a pretty basic task in any web programming.

Comment: if you are looking for user input try looking into php/html

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers where <Column> like '%MEXICO%';
```

'%' is the wildcard. So you will find:

"   MEXICO" 
   "MEXICO City" 
   "MX MEXICO"

If you want to use the wildcard you must use 'like' instead of '='

Comment: The question is about taking user input, not searching for partial matches to a search term.